# There is a way to send message between to computer by ther wifi device(no router between)

Tags: c#, wireless

to explain what i try to do:

it like im in the desert and try to send simple message (like:"hi")
between to computer no by bluetooth or ir only by them wifi device

it's suppost to use mac address i guese.

or if there any way to broadcast message like the rotuer broadcast his ssid wireless network name (ssid)

if there is any c# code or some article its will be great.
thanks.

Comment: Consider 1) Where the WiFi is running in "ad-hoc" mode 2) One of the device is a WiFi access-point (this doesn't have to be a router; for instance, I can turn my laptop into an AP if I feel like it) -- there is no need to go below the TCP/IP layer (and doing so is *not trivial*) if the network is correctly setup; in any case, this should be a start.

Comment: yes i know about this way "ad-hoc" bulid in in windows,about the ap way i  guess it is possible, but there is exmple how to do it by code or some article? (this answer is for krtek as well) thanks you all

Answer (score 0):

This is called Ad-Hoc Wireless networking and setting it up greatly depends on the operating system. Here's some basic explanation : http://compnetworking.about.com/cs/wirelessfaqs/f/adhocwireless.htm